# Win32 User Impersonation Curiosity

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, authentication

I have found some sample code [on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx) that allows for user impersonation.

This code works by importing the following unmanaged Win32 API functions:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int LogonUser(
    string lpszUserName,
    string lpszDomain,
    string lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType,
    int dwLogonProvider,
    ref IntPtr phToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,int impersonationLevel,ref IntPtr hNewToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
```

These functions are used to impersonate the target user, then perform some operations, then revert the impersonation context. Impersonating the user is achieved like so:

```
if ( LogonUser(userName, domainName, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token ) != 0 )
{
    if ( DuplicateToken( token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate ) != 0 )
    {
        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity( tokenDuplicate );
        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand why this code first gets the required token using `LogonUser`, then duplicates that token, before performing the impersonation on the duplicated token. Why not just impersonate using the token that you get from the `LogonUser` method.

Obviously the person that wrote this article understands this better than I do so it would appear that I am missing something. Could I please get an explanation of why the seemingly redundant token duplication step of this process is required?

Comment: it's codeproject, not codeplex, right?

Comment: Correct, yeah have updated this now thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, token, passed to WindowsIdentity ctor should be an **impersonation token**. So, the author of that code using

```
DuplicateToken( token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate )
```

to create an **impersonation token** from **primary token**, returned by LogonUser(). That '2' magic number stands for SecurityImpersonation member of SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL enum.

Links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Torvin, thanks for the response. That does make sense and I was thinking along those lines as well until I read this information in the "LogonUser" method documentation. "You can then use this token handle to impersonate the specified user or, in most cases, to create a process that runs in the context of the specified user." The reference for this is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx. So if this already allows for the impersonation, why would the duplication part be required?

Comment: Hmm, good question :) That code is buggy anyway: it never disposes created WindowsIdentity nor calls CloseHandle() on obtained tokens, thus leaking kernel handles.

Comment: Thanks Torvin, I do realize that though. The code I provided is only the relevant snippet from the article :D. Appreciate your thoughts and have voted you up.

Comment: I also found this piece of [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx). It basically does the same, but without `DuplicateHandle`, so I guess it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks torvin, I guess I can safely mark that part down as redundant then. -- Cheers